# Rearranging Table in R

Tags: r

I was wondering if someone could help me with taking a table that is set up in the following fashion:

```
Date   x    y    z  
5-3    12   43  23  
5-1    41   75  32  
9-5    21   43  60
```

And making a new table with the following format:

```
Number  Letter  
  12       x  
  43       y  
  23       z  
  41       x  
  75       y  
 ...      ...
```

The rows do not have to be ordered in any particular way, I just need all the number values in one column, and their associated column letter (in the original table) in the second column. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need the `Date` column?

Comment: No, it's not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot add a comment to @Frank's answer, I am posting my own. This works in base R.

This is essentially the same as *unpivot*-ing the table.

Using @Frank's dataframe `DF`:

```
DF_new=stack(subset(DF, select = -Date))
names(DF_new) <- c("Number", "Letter")
```

Or a one-liner:

```
DF_new=setNames(stack(subset(DF, select = -Date)),  c("Number", "Letter"))
```

Both give the result:

```
  Number Letter
1     12      x
2     41      x
3     21      x
4     43      y
5     75      y
6     43      y
7     23      z
8     32      z
9     60      z
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the reshape2 package:

```
> reshape2::melt(t(DF[, -1]), 
    varnames=c("Letter", "row"), 
    value.name = "Number")
  Letter row Number
1      x   1     12
2      y   1     43
3      z   1     23
4      x   2     41
5      y   2     75
6      z   2     32
7      x   3     21
8      y   3     43
9      z   3     60
```

Data:

```
DF = structure(list(Date = c("5-3", "5-1", "9-5"), x = c(12L, 41L, 
21L), y = c(43L, 75L, 43L), z = c(23L, 32L, 60L)), .Names = c("Date", 
"x", "y", "z"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```